# c++ error using sizeof(T) in static member of T

Tags: c++, sizeof

Why doesn't my compiler allow this?

```
class Resource
{
   private:
      static const int max_instances = 10;

      // set aside memory to be used later with placement new
      static char memory[max_instances * sizeof(Resource)]; // error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'Resource'
};
```

Comment: sizeof(Resource) is not known until Resource is defined.  But Resource's definition depends on sizeof(Resource).  It's circular.

Comment: Note you can work around this by just declaring `static char memory[];` within the class, and give the size at the actual member definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My old prescription, wrap it in a function:

```
class Resource{
    //...
    auto constexpr max_instances=10;

    static auto& memory(){
        static std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Resource),alignof(Resource)> storage[max_instances];
        return storage;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 6):

[[expr.sizeof]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sizeof#1):

> The `sizeof` operator shall not be applied to an expression that has function or incomplete type

[[class.mem]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mem#6), emphasis mine:

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type ([basic.types]) (or complete type) at the closing `}` of the *class-specifier*. Within the class *member-specification*, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments, *noexcept-specifier*s, and default member initializers (including such things in nested classes). **Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class *member-specification*.**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you haven't finished defining your class, hence complier doesn't know how much is it's size and thus producing this error. I have no idea what you're trying to acomplish here, go with aschepler's answer and define the static const char outside of the actual class definition

Comment: `max_instances` is static, so doesn't get storage within class objects. For the code given, `sizeof(Resource)==1` is likely, but I assume it's a simplified version of something with actual data for the question's sake.

Comment: Oh thanks for the notice, I will edit this answer immediately